# Twitter API parameters setup in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, twitter

So Twitter delivers a ready to use code:

`https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweets-and-users/quick-start/get-tweets`

I'm trying to edit it to get data from specifc accounts, hashtags.

I found that `const params` can accept couple values: `[ids,expansions,tweet.fields,media.fields,poll.fields,place.fields,user.fields]` however I can't find sample syntax on how to point to specifc Twitter account I want to monitor.

Pages I reviewed:

`https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/fields`

`https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet`

Provided code snippet I need to modify:

```
//available params [ids,expansions,tweet.fields,media.fields,poll.fields,place.fields,user.fields]'
const params = {
  ids: '1138505981460193280',
  'tweet.fields': 'created_at',
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find how to retrieve and explore the timeline of public Tweets a user has posted in this tutorial: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/explore-a-users-tweets

Make sure that you have all keys and tokens to connect and authenticate to the Twitter API.

You will need to adjust your query to get the right Tweets you want. For example, for the @TwitterDev account, you’d want to make sure the endpoint you are making a GET request to is: `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=from:TwitterDev`

Here is a sample code for Node.js:

```
const needle = require('needle');

// The code below sets the bearer token from your environment variables
// To set environment variables on Mac OS X, run the export command below from the terminal: 
// export BEARER_TOKEN='YOUR-TOKEN' 
const token = process.env.BEARER_TOKEN; 

const endpointUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent'

async function getRequest() {

    // Edit query parameters below
    const params = {
        'query': 'from:twitterdev -is:retweet', 
        'tweet.fields': 'author_id' 
    } 

    const res = await needle('get', endpointUrl, params, { headers: {
        "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }})

    if(res.body) {
        return res.body;
    } else {
        throw new Error ('Unsuccessful request')
    }
}

(async () => {

    try {
        // Make request
        const response = await getRequest();
        console.log(response)

    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
    process.exit();
  })();
```